# Accessing the first elements of all elements in an Array,built of a node list, JavaScript, DOM

Tags: javascript, sorting, dom, xhtml, html-table

I have the following problem:

I have to sort a XHTML-table, so I need the access to the first col. and then sorting the rows. My table looks so:

```
<table id="output">
<tr> 
   <td>Something</td> 
   <td>Element</td>
   <td>No idea what else</td> 
</tr>

<tr> 
   <td>A Something</td> 
   <td>Second element </td> 
   <td>No idea what else</td>
</tr>
 ... 
</table>
```

And this should be the result:

```
A Something        Element            No idea what
Something          Second element     No idea what
```

So... I make this with DOM tree, here is the function, where I have problems:

```
 var compare=function(a, b) {
        var x=a.firstChild.data;
        var y=b.firstChild.data;
        if(x>y) return -1;
        else if(y<x) return 1;
        else return 0;  
    }

    var sort=function() {
        var table=document.getElementById("output");
        var elementList=document.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //The node list
        var array_table=new Array();

            for(var i=0; i<elementList.length; i++) {
                array_table.push(elementList[i]); 
            }

           Here I need access to the td[0] in every tr-Element in the array.
           But with array_table.getElementsByTagName and the ready 
sort()-Function in JavaScript there is an error,that 
getElementsByTagname is not a function.

    //Evtl. appending at the end
         for(var j=0; j<array_table.length;j++){
            table.appendChild(array_table[j]); 
         }}
```

My question: How can I get access to the first `<td>` element in every row and compare the text? (I'm not allowed to use jQuery or any library)

Comment: This would be easier with jquery. Just use $('tr').children[0].text()

Comment: You can use *querySelectorAll* with a suitable selector, or you can just iterate over the rows and get the content of the first cell. There's really not much extra code (couple of lines?) over a jQuery solution (and you save 100kb of library).

Comment: @RobG for(i=0; i<array_table.length; i++){
    array_table[i].firstChild.sort();
   } When I try to iterate so over the rows I become the error: array_table... not a function; with array_table[i[0]]: array_table.sort(compare(array_table[i[0]],array_table[(i+1)[0])) /with modified for-loop before: for(...i<array_table.length-1...) Now I have error in the compare function,could you offer me an idea, i mean not ready solution or ready code, but an idea, from which I can start? I would be grateful, because Im trying this for more than week and I think I tried almost every alternative for iterating

Answer (score 1):

you can get all the first `td` of all `tr`, you can do that by:

```
// Get all TRs
var trs = document.querySelectorAll('#output tr');

// get first TD in each TR
for (var index=0; index<trs.length; ++index) {
  var firstTD = trs[index][0];
  // your code ...
}
```

Comment: To get the TDs in the first column: `document.querySelectorAll('#output tr td:first-child')`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to get the rows you want to sort into an array, then sort based on the value in the first cell, then return the rows to the table in order. The following is just a proof of concept, you can take it further in your own code but keep it simple.

```js
function toArray(a) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=a.length; i<iLen; i++) arr[i] = a[i];
  return arr;
}

function sortTable(){
  // Get first tbody in document
  var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  // Get rows of tbody
  var rows = tbody.querySelectorAll('tr');
  // Convert to Array
  rows = toArray(rows);
  // Sort rows in array
  rows.sort(function(a, b){return a.cells[0].textContent - b.cells[0].textContent});
  // Put back in table in order
  rows.forEach(function(row) {tbody.appendChild(row)});
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>A<td>B
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>0<td>foo
    <tr><td>5<td>foo
    <tr><td>3<td>foo
    <tr><td>1<td>foo
    <tr><td>2<td>foo
    <tr><td>4<td>foo
</table>
      
<button onclick="sortTable()">Sort on first column</button>
```

Note that you can replace *tbody.querySelectorAll('tr')* with *tbody.rows* or *tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr')*.

The *toArray* function is deliberately simple, it won't handle sparse arrays well (it will add missing members with a value of undefined). It's necessary because Chrome doesn't like sorting collections for some reason. You might also need a shim for *forEach* for IE 8.

PS.

If you want a "one liner" and have a very recent javascript implementation, the above can be compressed into the following that uses no libraries or separate functions (I'm not a big fan of such stuff, this is just to show it can be done, not to suggest that it should be done):

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#output tbody tr td:first-child'))
    .sort(function(a,b){return a.innerText - b.innerText})
    .forEach(function(cell){cell.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(cell.parentNode)});
```

Comment: The OP says it's XHTML, so your HTML source is invalid.

Comment: @MrLister—it's an example, the important part is the script, not the markup which is deliberately minimal.